# Reading HTTP Header in ActionScript2

Tags: http, http-headers, actionscript-2

In AS2, I need to get a URL.  In the header of the HTTP response, a cookie is set.  Is it possible to read the header of the HTTP response and get the cookie's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. What you might have to do, is use a serverside script to get the HTTP request header, then call that script from flash.